# How host on github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vite

I host my vitejs project on github pages, and I'm getting this in the command console

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

my project https://github.com/LifeAsDev/intro

should display correctly

Comment: Did you check [the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages)?

Comment: You have to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

**`.jsx` files are not javascript**

"jsx" stands for "JavaScript XML" and can be included directly in HTML using a script tag attribute of `type="jsx"` instead of `type="module"`.  But browsers won't compile such files automatically - the page would also need to include script tags in `index.html`to load react standalone dev mode files from a CDN. The standalone react files would then compile `.jsx` files into JavaScript using babel each time the page is loaded. This may be suitable for demonstration purposes since (presumably) the file will not be used for production.

Another alternative would be to build a react app from your project which, in the process, would compile `jsx` files into JavaScript using babel. A tutorial for this that uses `create-react-app` is available on GitHub at [Deploying a React App to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#readme)